# So I wrote a program... Now how do I package it and automate the install?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, packages

I wrote a very simple Linux program which is essentially made up of: a bash script, four python scripts and a text file. I want to package it all together so that when people install it, it automatically distributes itself in this fashion:

```
text file         go to    /  
bash script       go to    /usr/bin/  
python scripts    go to    /usr/bin/.programnamehere/
```

I know these aren't the proper places to put things for a proper application, this is just something quick I wrote to familiarize myself with this process.

Now, I could pack all of these files into a archive and add a separate "install" script to move copy everything around and then delete the originals, but I would rather do it via some other method (like apt-get).

I read a bit of the apt-get documentation and I really am not sure if this process is what would happen if I go that route?

If anyone has any suggestions on what I should do or links to something relevant, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You really shouldn't put anything into `/`. Depending on its purpose, your text file might fit into `/usr/share/doc/yourpackagename`.

Comment: If you prefer an apt-get-like installation over an install script, and you are satisfied with your program being installable on Debian/Ubuntu, this might help you: https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian

Comment: @n.st yeah I know it's not really a good idea. The file is something that I need every user on the computer to be able to read and write, I can't find another place in the filesystem where I can do that, because if I give the file full permissions, it's still inside of a directory that doesn't have full permissions, so it doesn't work for lower level users. Do you know another way around this problem? Putting it in / is the only solution I've found so far.

Comment: You might want to consider `/usr/share/yourprogramname`, or `/etc/yourprogramname` if it's a config file. Could you tell us what your program actually does and what those files contain, so we can decide where they should be stored?

Comment: @n.st basically the program is a simple guestbook that you can sign, and it adds additional data like the date and time. You can also delete it (though I might make it so only root can do that). Unless it's in a shared directory, when a user looks at it, he won't see any other entries than his own. The program is just an initial version of a more complex logging program that I'm writing (logs user activities), so this feature isn't gonna be in the final version. But for now I want it to work as a simple guestbook, so I can learn how to properly write, package and distribute a full program.

Comment: So the text file contains the actual guestbook content? It should probably live somewhere in `/var/` then. Now, as for the bash script, putting it into `/usr/bin/` is okay, but `/usr/local/bin/` would be better. The directory for the python scripts doesn't need to (and shouldn't) be hidden, so you might want to use `/usr/local/bin/myguestbook/` (without the leading dot) instead.

Comment: Also posted here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/333974/so-i-wrote-a-program-now-how-do-i-package-it-and-automate-the-install

Comment: @ vasa1 yes I thought askubuntu was a more appropriate place for this question but for some reason no one ever answers questions there, just look at the front page! this forums is better

Comment: @n.st ok I'll try your suggestions right now, hopefully they work in those locations

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking to make a "Debian binary package" directly without source package.

`equivs` is is very simple tool that allows making trivial Debian packages, through simple wizard to generate `DEBIAN/control` and other required files.

Available from Debian and Ubuntu repository.